# Convert spark scala dataset to specific RDD format

Tags: scala, rdd, apache-spark-dataset

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
+--------------------+-----------------+
|     recommendations|relevant_products|
+--------------------+-----------------+
|[12949, 12949, 71...|           [4343]|
|[12949, 12949, 71...|           [1589]|
|[12949, 12949, 71...|          [11497]|
```

`evaluation_ds:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[docCompare] = [recommendations: array, relevant_products: array]`

This is the class used in the dataset: `case class docCompare (recommendations: Array[Int], relevant_products: Array[Int])`

How can I convert it to a JavaRDD in the following format:

```
 org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Array[?], Array[?])]
```

Comment: When I call `.rdd.take(1)` I get  `relevantDocuments: Array[docCompare] = Array(docCompare([I@2ffc7a3,[I@5c0b730b))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply apply [rdd](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@rdd:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T]) to the Dataset, as shown below:

```
val evaluation_ds = Seq(
  (Seq(3446, 3843, 1809), Seq(1249)),
  (Seq(4557, 4954, 2920), Seq(2360))
).toDF("recommendations", "relevant_products").as[(Array[Int], Array[Int])]

import org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.RankingMetrics

val metrics = new RankingMetrics(evaluation_ds.rdd)
// metrics: org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.RankingMetrics[Int] = ...
```